# New user flow with Admob on a freemium app

Tags: android, ios, admob

I had a freemium app serving Admob ads and since I could not figure out how to be GDPR compliant for May 25th I decided to remove Admob completely from my app before I can figure it out. Google released a consent SDK not even 2 weeks before the deadline so I decided to play it safe.

I now have a freemium app that asks you nicely to buy the premium without serving any ads... and I'd like to change that, but I don't know how.

I did some research, from what I know about GDPR:

1. You need user consent before you serve ads, regardless of whether they are personalized or not: [admob doc here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent)
2. If the user does not grant consent, you should not collect any of their personal data, which means Admob can't work because it can't track them
3. If the user refuses to grant consent, they should not suffer from the consequences (aka close the app and refuse to work without consent) because that would then mean that the consent would not be [freely given](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-43/)

I'm not a lawyer and I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around this.

My assumption at this point is that the only way to show ads in an app while being GDPR compliant would be to:

- Show a prompt on first app start to ask user for consent
- When asking for consent, you need to clearly state that you need their consent to track them to be able to serve ads (who would say yes to that?)
- If consent given, then serve ads
- If consent not given, then do not serve ads

Is my assumption correct? Is that really the way to go to serve ads in an app? Or am I missing something? If anyone is in a similar situation and found a better way I would love to know about it!

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped my head around this as well. I can show you what I did with my iOS app. I'm only using Admob in my app. I do not have any third party analytics framework or else in my app. So, to get to your questions. I'm not a lawyer as well, so that is just from developer to developer ;)

> Show a prompt on first app start to ask user for consent

Yes, that's correct. Also you need to give the user a setting to revoke their consent.

> When asking for consent, you need to clearly state that you need their consent to track them to be able to serve ads (who would say yes to that?)

When you use the `PersonalizedAdConsent` framework from Google the you have the options: see relevant ads that are personalised or see non relevant ads that are non personalised. You can also add the option for a paid version of the app but that is optional.

> If consent given, then serve ads

Yes, then you can serve personalised ads

> If consent not given, then do not serve ads

As far as I know then you can only serve non-personalised ads to the user.

Here you can see the dialogue that shows up in my iOS App: [NFC Reader for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nfc-reader-for-iphone/id1249686798?mt=8)

I Hope I could help you a bit

[image: NFC Reader for iPhone ad consent screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience! From the "admob doc here" link in my question, I think you are not allowed to serve ads at all without user consent. If you check the doc I linked, it explicitly says "Ads served by Google can be categorized as personalized or non-personalized, both requiring consent from users in the EEA." I would say an implementation where you end up serving non-personalized ads to a user who refused any type of tracking is not GDPR compliant...

Comment: @androidseb I think I am getting the consent from the user. The "No" option is a consent for non personalised ads. If someone does not want to give me the consent then he/she has to delete the app.  Many websites out there hiding their content behind a consent wall. So I think that is the way to go nowadays...

Comment: what you say makes sense, but according to the GDPR regulation (see link in point 3 in my original question) this "way to go" that you describe is a GDPR violation because the consent is not "freely given". The text I linked says: "Consent is presumed not to be freely given [...] if [...] the provision of a service, is dependent on the consent despite such consent not being necessary for such performance." In your case, your app doesn't need to track user data to function.